# What causes the milk percentage to rise?

Tags: cookie-clicker

In cookie clicker, what causes the milk percentage to rise?

I had a hundred percent, but now I have 106% and I have no idea where it came from. Now I also got the milk turned into raspberry juice and the value is up to 228%

Comment: See also: [How much more CpS do kittens give?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/252700/30863)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### The answer to your question

The base amount of milk is 0%. The current formula for calculating milk is `milk = achievements / 25`. That means that for every achievement, you get 4% milk.

<s>Are you sure 58 is the number shown in the stats page? I currently have 40 achievements, giving me 160% milk (as expected).</s>

I have just discovered that **not all achievements count**. The August 27th update states:

> due to popular demand, retired 5 achievements (the "reset your game" and "cheat" ones); they can still be unlocked, but do not count toward your total anymore.

If you hover over one of these achievements, it'll say [Shadow] in the tooltip. An example of this is:

> Uncanny clicker ("Beat the clicking speed world record."):
>  [image: Demonstration of the Shadow tag in the achievement.]
>  I got this through using MouseKeys to sort of gain an advantage :P

This means that even though it's displayed in the stats page, it *doesn't actually count* when calculating milk %. Thus, even though I have 42 achievements, since one of them is a [Shadow] achievement, the game calculates my milk as 41 / 25 = 164%.

#### More milk facts!

The text next to milk is just flavour text. When milk is less than 100%, it's simply *plain milk*. When it's at least 100% but less than 200%, it's *chocolate milk*. Otherwise, if it's at least 200%, it's *raspberry juice*.

Milk will only affect Cookies Per Second (CpS) if you have at least one kitten upgrade. The first one, *Kitten helpers*, is unlocked at 50% milk and adds a `0.05 * milk` multiplier. (For instance, at 50% milk, your CpS will be multiplied by 1.025.)

The other upgrades are:

> At 100% milk, *Kitten workers*. This adds an additional multiplier of `0.1 * milk`.
>  At 200% milk, *Kitten engineers*. This adds an additional multiplier of `0.2 * milk`.
>
>  Thus, at 200% milk with all Kitten upgrades, your CpS is multiplied by 1.1, then 1.2, then 1.4, for a total multiplier of 1.848.

**Note**: sometimes, for whatever reason, getting a new achievement while owning at least one Kitten upgrade will not change your CpS. To force the game to recalculate your CpS, go to your address bar and type in `javascript:Game.CalculateGains()` or `javascript:Game.recalculateGains=1`.

<sup>Interestingly, a comment in the code says it should be 1% per achievement and that raspberry juice should be strawberry juice...</sup>

Comment: Interestingly enough, 69 / 25 = 276%, but I have 268% milk. It seems inconsistent even though the code seems very clear about this. It seems to *ignore* 2 achievements for whatever reason. [http://i.imgur.com/UJQDfpN.png](http://i.imgur.com/UJQDfpN.png) It uses the same achievement amount variable to count milk and show the unlocked achievements, though.

Comment: @3ventic There, edited with explanation. Tsk tsk, I see you've been cheating :P

Comment: I might have :P