# How much more CpS do kittens give?

Tags: cookie-clicker

The upgrade for Kitten helpers says you gain more CpS the more milk I have. What is the exact amount that the kittens give? (just the percentage is ok)

Comment: See also: [What causes the milk percentage to rise?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/129144/30863)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are 5 different kitten upgrades, with them being named Kitten helpers, Kitten workers, Kitten engineers, Kitten overseers, and Kitten managers.

The **Kitten helpers** upgrade gives you a bonus of **5%** per 100 percentage points of milk (Ex. 1.05x for 100pp milk)

The **Kitten workers** upgrade gives you a bonus of **10%** per 100 percentage points of milk (Ex. 1.10x for 100pp milk)

The **Kitten engineers** upgrade gives you a bonus *6*of **20%** per 100 percentage points of milk (Ex. 1.20x for 100pp milk)

The **Kitten overseers** upgrade gives you a bonus of **20%** per 100 percentage points of milk (Ex. 1.20x for 100pp milk)

The **Kitten managers** upgrade gives you a bonus of **20%** per 100 percentage points of milk (Ex. 1.20x for 100pp milk)

Remember, the upgrades stack multiplicatively, so the fourth will give a bigger boost than the third.

[Source](http://cookieclicker.wikia.com/wiki/Upgrade#Kitten_Upgrades)

Comment: A sight addition to the current explanation. I am aware of six different kitten upgrades, not five. The sixth is Kitten Experts.

Answer (score -3):

You'll usually always double your current CPS with kittens.

Comment: According to everything that I have seen, that isn't true.

Comment: it can work as a rule of thumb in later stages for the 20% upgrades

Comment: It used to be the case a while back, I haven't kept in touch with it. As long as you have high milk it's quite beneficial to upgrading it.